# Proof of convergence of alternative minimization/maximization

Tags: reference-request, optimization, proofs

Given a problem

\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in X} \min_{y \in Y}  f(x,y)
\end{equation}

where $f$ is strongly convex in $Y$ and strongly concave in $X$

How to show that the following iterative processes will finally converge and how is the speed?

\begin{equation}
x_k=\arg\max_{x \in X} f(x,y_{k-1})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y_k=\arg\min_{y \in Y} f(x_{k-1},y)
\end{equation}

**UPDATE 1**: *The problem is being rewritten in order to distinguish from [another question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24975/iteratively-minimizing-the-function) which looks similar.*

**UPDATE 2**: *The function $f$ is now strongly convex in $Y$ and strongly concave in $X$*

Comment: @RB Thanks for pointing this out. I have rewritten the problem.

Comment: As mentioned at the other question convexity (concavity) itself isn't enough. Without being strongly convex this isn't guaranteed to converge.

Comment: You should edit your original question instead.  I am closing this one.

Comment: @RB Thanks, I have updated the function as strongly convex in $Y$ and strongly concave in $X$

Comment: @LevReyzin Thanks for pointing this out. I have modified the question so now it asks for proof.

Comment: It doesn't matter, if the problem is not jointly convex in both variables, there are no general guarantees. It does sometimes work quite well, though.